# Parameter 1 of constructor UtilSpanner required a bean of type 'io.micrometer.tracing.Propagator$Getter' that could not be found

Tags: java, apache-kafka, micrometer

I am trying to upgrade my application to Java 17 , my application is a gradle project and I am using micrometer propagator in place of Spring sleuth propagator for some specific reason.Below is the code i am using ,

```
import io.micrometer.tracing.Span;
import io.micrometer.tracing.SPanAndScope;
import io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer;
........


@Component
public class UtilSpanner implements BiFunction<AtomicReference<SpanAndScope>, RecieverRecord<String, ScheduleKafka>,RecieverRecord<String,ScheduleKafka>> {

private final Tracer tracer;
private final Propagator.Getter<ConsumerRecord<?,?>> extractor; 
private final Propagator propagator;

public UtilSpanner(Tracer tracer, Propagator.Getter<ConsumerRecord<?,?>> extractor //here is the problem i am getting 
, Propagator propagator){
 this.tracer = tracer;
 this.extractor = extractor;
 this.propagator = propagator;
}
```

I am getting problem in the paramater 1 of the constructor where it is not able to identify the Propagator.Getter.

Below is the gradle dependency i am using regarding micrometer

```
   plugins{
     id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
     id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
     ......
}

implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.10.6'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-promethus:1.10.6'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-cuircuitbreaker-reactor-resiliance4j:3.0.1'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing:latest.integration'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-observation'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Since `Propagator.Getter` is context-dependent, you need to define it on your own, e.g.:

```java
propagator.extract(request, (record, key) -> record.getHeader(key));
```

Also, a few things were redesigned, please look into the `io.micrometer.observation.transport` package where you also find the `Propagator` interface, it has `RequestReplyReceiverContext` and  `ReceiverContext` that might be useful to you (and how they are used).